# SSH from Mac to Vagrant machine

Tags: macos, ssh, vagrant

I am trying to connect with SSH from my MacBook to a Vagrant machine.

`vagrant ssh` works fine, but I'm wondering why it is failing when I use `ssh` from the Mac Terminal.

Here is the error it throws:

```
Raghavendras-MacBook-Pro:~ raghu$ ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you are issuing a "plain" `ssh` command and in result you are trying to login to the VM using your default `id_rsa`+`id_rsa.pub` key-pair.

Unless you explicitly added `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the MacBook to the `~/.ssh/accepted_keys` of the `vagrant` account on the VM, your default key-pair is unknown to the VM and will be rejected with the "Permission denied" message you get.

---

You can use a key that Vagrant creates and injects into the machine upon creation. Run the following from the project directory, replacing `<machine_id>` with the name you configured in the Vagrantfile (also assuming you are using VirtualBox, otherwise change that part of the path too):

```
ssh -i .vagrant/machines/<machine_id>/virtualbox/private_key -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` should work fine, but sometimes Vagrant changes the port it’s forwarding to the localhost so the `-p 2222` won’t work.

So double-check what port SSH is being forwarded on/from and use that port number instead.

A simple way to check that is to `vagrant ssh` from your Vagrant setup directory and then in another shell/terminal window run this command:

```
ps aux | grep ssh
```

There should be a line in there that shows you exactly how the SSH connection was established that looks like this:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2226 -o Compression=yes -o DSAAuthentication=yes -o LogLevel=FATAL -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /path/to/Vagrant/.vagrant/machines/nodejs/virtualbox/private_key
```

Ignore the bulk of that command unless you care about password-less access. Just note this first part:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2226
```

That is the command—in my example—where the forwarded SSH post is `2226`. That works in my case. And if you are prompted for a password for some reason, remember the default Vagrant user is `vagrant` and the default password for that user is… `vagrant`.